# Windows Installer XML (WiX)

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, bootstrapper

My application needs .Net Framework 3.5, Crystal Report 10.5 and SQLServer Express 2005 as pre-requisites. For this purpose I created a wix setup project and added the msbuild task for prerequisites. 
My current problem
When installing the kit to an user machine, crystal report trying to install before .net framework 3.5. 
How can I change the order of the prerequisites?

My current msbuild task code is given below;

```
  <ItemGroup>
<BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5">
  <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
<BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
  <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
<BootstrapperFile Include="BusinessObjects.CrystalReports.10.5">
  <ProductName>Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 (x86, x64)</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
<BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.9.2">
  <ProductName>SQL Server 2005 Express Edition SP2 (x86)</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
```

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" 
ApplicationName="Business Software" 
BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" 
ComponentsLocation="Relative" 
CopyComponents="True" 
OutputPath="$(OutputPath)\en-us\" 
Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\" />
```

Comment: It seems that you didn't format the code as code block, that's why the XML in your sample is invisible...

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471405/bootstrapper-prerequisite-ordering

Comment: I checked the post Wimmel noticed. The product.xml of Crystal Reports already depends on Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0. In my scenario I am installing the .net framework 3.5 and it includes framework 2 also. Then why the crystal reports trying to install first?

Comment: Can you add the `<RelatedProducts>` part of both product.xml files above?

Comment: What does a Visual Studio Bootstrapper question have to do with WiX?  I'd like to remove the WiX tag.

Comment: Product.xml for both .Net framework 3.5 and crystal reports are the default ones visual studio supplied. Crystal reports depends on product Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0 and .Net framework 3.5 depends on windows installer 3.1 and includes products Framework 2.0 and 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is rectified by replacing the DependsOnProduct tag in CrystalReports10_5\products.xml as follows

```
  <RelatedProducts>
<!--<DependsOnProduct Code="Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0" />-->
<DependsOnProduct Code="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [dotnetinstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/).

It is a free tool and the benefit of using dotnetinstaller is you can merge your msi with that and can generate an exe which can be executed an administrator unlike msi file.

In dotnetinstaller you can have pre-conditions defined and much more.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sunil. I have to correct the issues of existing installation kit. A bootstrapper change is not a good option for me.